Using scrapy-playwright to scrape Amazon ASINs
While trying to scrape 'Amazon Standard Identification Numbers' my code is running fine but some of the asin values are missing from the output. I have checked the html tags, all the asin values are in 'div' element's 'data-asin' attribute. I don't understand why some values are missing.
import scrapy
from amazon.items import AmazonItem
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&crid=3HPDQBP5QI5QM&sprefix=lap%2Caps%2C672&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_3'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta= dict(
            playwright =  True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods = [
                PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div[data-asin]'),
                PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"),
                PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div[data-asin]:nth-child(23)")
            ],
            errback = self.errback
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

        for product in response.css('div[data-asin]'):
            asin = product.css('::attr(data-asin)').get()
            yield {
                "asin": asin
            }

    async def errback(self,failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

This is the code i have written.

Try this and see what your crawler sees:
# add this
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

And
async def parse(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)

This should open the page content in a browser, look for details & do further fixes accordingly.
